# Difference between using arrow functions to declare method and function() when assigning the method to a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

If I have the following code:

```
let myObject = {
   greeting: "Hi",

   greet1(message) {
       return(console.log(`${this.greeting} ${message}`));
   },

   greet2() {
       return(message => console.log(`${this.greeting} ${message}`));
   }
}


greeting = "Hello";

anotherGreet1 = myObject.greet1;
anotherGreet1("It is sunny today");

anotherGreet2 = myObject.greet2(); // Why is there a parenthesis here?
anotherGreet2("It is raining today"); // Doesn't run unless previous line has ()
```

Why is it that when I assign `anotherGreet1` with the function `greet1` I don't need to use parentheses, but to assign `greet2` to `anotherGreet2` I need to use parenthesis? I understand that in assigning a function to a variable I want to assign the *entire* function and not just it's return value. This logic makes sense for `greet1` but doesn't hold for `greet2`.

Comment: Because return value of `greet1` is string, while `greet2` is function, so in `greet2` you must call that returned arrow function once move: `myObject.greet2()()`

Comment: @Justinas That's just answered my question. I didn't know that the return value would be a function. Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `greet1` is function that first processes `console.log(...)` and only then returns it's value as string: `myObject.greet1()`

Your `greet2` if function that returns another function. You must call that function once more to be able to get output of `console.log(...)`: `myObject.greet2()()`